# HQL: using elements() on objects

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

say I have a database with two tables: classes and students.  Each table contains metadata about the relevant topic.  For example, classes contains fields 'classid', 'name' and 'room_number' and students contains fields 'name', 'classid', 'age' and 'height' (say a student can only be in one class).

What if I want to write an HQL query to get me all classes that include students with names 'Joe', 'Bob', and 'Fred'?  If students only contained 'classid' and 'name' I think I could write the following in HQL.

```
from Classes as class where
  'Joe' in elements(class.students) and
  'Bob' in elements(class.students) and
  'Fred' in elements(class.students)
```

However, students is an object in this case.  Do I need to perform the joins explicitly?

```
from Classes as class
  join class.students as s1
  join class.students as s2
  join class.students as s2
where
  s1.name = 'Joe'
  s2.name = 'Bob'
  s3.name = 'Fred'
```

I imagine that using `'Fred' in elements` also performs these joins, but it is much more compact to write!  Or is there a better way of doing this altogether?

Comment: I could also use subqueries.  I would guess that the joins are more easily optimizable--but I really don't know.  Is there an easy way to compose the nested subqueries?

Answer (score 7):

Use a sub-select:

```
from Classes c 
where c.classid in(
      select s.classid from students s where s.name in('Joe', 'Bob', 'Fred')
   )
```

Comment: My query selects classes that contain all three students 'Joe', 'Bob' AND 'Fred'.  You query selects classes that contains 'Joe', 'Bob', OR 'Fred'.